# Can I use pine script's ternary operator to specify the style argument in plotshape() or the char argument in plotchar()?

Tags: plot, conditional-operator, pine-script

I imagine that I am asking pine script to do something it is not designed to do, but I thought I would put out the question anyway.

Can I use pine script's ternary operator to specify the style argument in plotshape() or the char argument in plotchar()?

For example, something like this:

```
plotshape(
     volume, 
     style = (close[0] >= close[1]) ? shape.square : shape.xcross,
     color = color.red
     )
```

or something like this:

```
plotchar(
     volume, 
     char  = (close[0] >= close[1]) ? "#" : "•",
     color = color.red
     )
```

EDIT: added example of `label.new()` applied to the volume pane—but without the ability to properly specify the `y`, `y_loc` or `style`:

[image: Volume Plot]

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. `style`'s type is `style (input string)`, which means its value must be known before script execution. For its value to be determined at runtime, it would need to be of type `"series[string]"`.

You can tell this if you try to compile what you are trying to do.

You will get the following error.

```
line 7: Cannot call 'plotshape' with arguments (series=series[bool], title=literal string, style=series[string], location=const string); available overloads: plotshape(series[bool], const string, input string, input string, series[color], input integer, series[integer], const string, series[color], const bool, const string, input integer, const integer, string) => void; plotshape(fun_arg__<arg_series_type>, const string, input string, input string, fun_arg__<arg_color_type>, input integer, series[integer], const string, fun_arg__<arg_textcolor_type>, const bool, const string, input integer, const integer, string) => void
```

In the very first paranthesis, it tells you that it cannot call this function with `style=series[string]`, which is what you are trying to do by passing a variable that might have different values at runtime.

---

**EDIT:**
You can always combine your conditions in the `series` parameter of a plot. It will only plot if the series evaluates to `true`. So, two plot functions for two shapes.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)
mainCond = close > 0
circleCond = close > open
squareCond = open >= close
plotshape(series=mainCond and circleCond, title="Circle", style=shape.circle, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green)
plotshape(series=mainCond and squareCond, title="Square", style=shape.square, location=location.belowbar, color=color.red)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Baris Yakut.  I was hoping there might be some back-door way of conditionally plotting one of n chars within a single call of ```plotchar()```—similar to how we can do so with colors.  However, I'll certainly take your word for it that it is not structurally possible.

Comment: Please see my edit for a possible workaround. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestions. I was actually trying to get away from this specific approach: writing out an entire ```plotchar()``` for every possible scenario/condition.  Both for keeping the code concise and also because of the 64 item output limit, I was hoping there might be a way to sneak the conditioner into a single plot statement.

Comment: For example, it would be great to allow a user to access a drop-down box from which to choose from various different shapes or characters—without having to manipulate the code directly.  However, the code required to offer these numerous options (given Pine script's limitations) would end up being pretty cluttered and would quickly eat into the output limit, for something that could potentially be helpful for a user, but a hug waste of resources to sit around unused.

Comment: brilliant as far as combining the conditions in the series parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to plot different characters, use the **v4** `label`.
The string in it can be non-constant.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Andre: by "v4 label" are you referring to specifying ```//@version=4``` at the beginning of the script?  If so, I was testing this idea in version 4, but left out any info that I though might be necessary for my question.  According to @Baris Yakut, however, it doesn't seem to matter, since my intent is seemingly not possible within Pine's framework.  Do you believe there is some other way to conditionally plot one of two chars within a single ```plotchar()``` statement?

Comment: Hey Zwi, I updated my answer with an example that might get you what you're looking for, using a single `label.new()`. Doing it with a single `plotchar()` however, is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying (and providing an example) that you actually were referring to ```label.new()```.  I considered using labels but they tend to clutter the chart, so I decided to be content with merely color as a marker of relevant information (as opposed to color/shape pairs, as I originally intended).  That said, I have used labels in the past to display contingent text on the chart, so I should have been able to figure out that's what you were referring to…

Comment: I was planning to provide an example of what I did, but I'm not finding the option to post the photo?

Comment: It just occurred to me that I can use your ```label.new()``` suggestion and specify ```stye=label.style_none``` in order to keep the chart clean while also still being able to manipulate the character and color contingently.  Thanks!

Comment: It seems I am still flailing: I am actually adding these ```plotshape()```, ```plotchar()```, and ```label,new()``` calls to the volume panel.  Although label.new() will allow me to add a conditionally-specified color/char, I am unable to manipulate its placement or location—I am even having a hard time successfully specifying a style other than ```stye=label.style_none```.

Comment: The major problem with this is that my plotted characters fall out of visibility, Unless my volume panel is maximized, or my man chart is very small.  Any suggestions?  I realize that you uploaded a photo by editing your original post—I'll do the same, in case that is useful.